# InvalidArgumentError: slice index 1 of dimension 2 out of bounds when training GRU RNN

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, recurrent-neural-network

I'm a newbie in the world of recurrent neural networks and I am trying to follow a [TensorFlow tutorial](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/structured_data/time_series). This tutorial makes forecasting on weather time series data, and trains a LSTM model for it also. I want to make another RNN of type GRU for it to compare its performance to the LSTM model, but when I try to plot it with the [plot method of WindowGenerator class](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/structured_data/time_series#3_plot) defined in this tutorial I get the following error:

> InvalidArgumentError: slice index 1 of dimension 2 out of bounds.
> [Op:StridedSlice] name: strided_slice/

What's the problem and how can I fix it?

The code I wrote:

```
wide_window.plot(gru_model)
```

The GRU model:

```
gru_model = tf.keras.models.Sequential([
    tf.keras.layers.GRU(32, return_sequences=True),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(units=1)
])
print('Input shape:', wide_window.example[0].shape)
print('Output shape:', gru_model(wide_window.example[0]).shape)
```

> Input shape: (32, 24, 19)
> Output shape: (32, 24, 1)

After this I train and evaluate it.

And the wide_window definition:

```
wide_window = WindowGenerator(input_width=24, label_width=24, shift=1, label_columns=['T (degC)'])
```